# SGBD Setando todas as colunas notnull automaticamene

Tags: mysql

Existe alguma configuração no sgbd que obrigue o banco a setar todas as colunas de uma tabela como notnull?
Sempre quando importo alguma base de dados ou crio uma tabela em meu BD, todas as colunas recebem o valor not null. Gostaria de resolver isso.

Comment: O padrão é `NOT NULL`. Se você quer permitir valores nulos, precisa especificar a coluna como NULL no momento da criação da tabela (nos `CREATE TABLE` dentro desse arquivo que você está importando).

Comment: Eu especifico, mas não adianta. Inclusive estou usando doctrine. E estou setando os a propriedade "nullable=true" e o problema tende a persistir. E além disso, o banco que fiz um teste de importação, tinha colunas com propriedades setadas para permitir valores nulos, o que no meu banco foram passadas para "not null" automaticamente.

Comment: `nullable="true"` é para permitir valores nulos

Comment: Sim. Essa era a intenção. Permitir valores nulos. O que não está acontencendo.

Comment: Não entendi bem. Se você está importando as tabelas (de um arquivo .sql, presumo), já não seria tarde demais para o doctrine alterar qualquer coisa?

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não me expressei direito. Seguinte, eu fiz 2 testes. O primeiro eu crio a classe no doctrine com as propriedades "nullable=true" (pois desejo que os campos recebam null), no entanto ao executar o doctrine e o mesmo criar a tabela no banco, as colunas que setei como nullable=true encontra-se todas como not null. Sendo assim, executei outro teste, desta vez sem uso do doctrine, simplesmente importei uma base dados em para outro database utilizando o dump via workbench. Os campos que estavam setados como null na base importada foram substituidas para not null no meu banco.